# how to send HTML template mail via sendGrid API

Tags: email, sendgrid

i am not able to send HTML template mail via sendGrid API using curl.
i have design a html templates in separate file.
when i am sending using url it goes but in text format every html tags are as text.

Comment: Please post the curl call you are using.